# Using Firebase Custom Claims to conditionally render a UI in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm currently building a react native project with firebase and I would like to use the custom claims to conditionally render a Navigator.
Looking at the firebase documentation the example they give is:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
  .then((idTokenResult) => {
     // Confirm the user is an Admin.
     if (!!idTokenResult.claims.admin) {
       // Show admin UI.
       showAdminUI();
     } else {
       // Show regular user UI.
       showRegularUI();
     }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

So trying to convert it to react native this is what I came up with:

```
export default function UINav () {
return firebase
    .auth()
    .currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
    .then((tokenResult) => {
      if (tokenResult.claims.admin) {
        return (
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
              mode="modal"
            >
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Admin"
                component={AdminNavigator}
              />
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        )
      } else {
        return (
          <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
              mode="modal"
            >
              <>
                <Stack.Screen
                  name="User"
                  component={UserNavigator}
                />
              </>
            </Stack.Navigator>
          </NavigationContainer>
        )
      }
    })

}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {_U, _V, _W, _X}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing it like this

```
const Display = () => {
  const [toDisplay, setToDisplay] = useState(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator mode="modal">
        <>
          <Stack.Screen name="User" component={UserNavigator} />
        </>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>,
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    firebase
      .auth()
      .currentUser.getIdTokenResult()
      .then((tokenResult) => {
        if (tokenResult.claims.admin) {
          setToDisplay(
            <NavigationContainer>
              <Stack.Navigator mode="modal">
                <Stack.Screen name="Admin" component={AdminNavigator} />
              </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>,
          );
        }
      });
  }, []);

  return toDisplay;
};

export default function UINav() {
  return <Display />;
}
```

Don't forget to import useEffect & useState from React.